# Is stripes a small footprint framework to make a small web application in a coporate enviroment?

Tags: java, web-applications, stripes

I am looking to make a small web application for my group. The issue is the IT team makes having a server etc... impossible. The application would be a custom searchable database web-app. I am restricted to just having a folder on a network drive. I cannot have any installation on the users' machines. I was reading that web-apps might work. I could have all the information on the network drive everyone has access to and users can just type the address in their browser and fire up the web-app. I came across stripes and I am wondering if it fits the bill. There cannot be any footprint other than files in a folder. And many users need to access the files also. I also want it not to require much beyond a Windows OS. Will this work? The application is not really complicated. IT is not helping me but would be a great time saver for the group.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripes is a really good, lightweight Java web application framework.

However, it won't work without a sever. So, to answer your question, the simple answer is: **no**.

Your requirements are absolutely not a recommended scenario, especially in a corporate environment. I'd always opt for a simple DB-based solution.

You could, however, and if your corporate data security guidelines permit it, use a (free) Google App Engine account, to run your Stripes application. Of course, any other free or cheap platform will do.

Comment: sigh... when you mean DB-based solution, is that like have like an MS access setup or something on a single machine. How about a java embedded applet. Does that need a server?

Comment: Of course, you could use an applet embedded in a website. However, in your scenario, writing to a file on a filesystem, you had to take care about a lot of details, you wouldn't need with a proper server-based solution. Just think about concurrent (write) access of multiple users to that file, transaction handling, locking etc. I wouldn't do that.

Comment: OK one more follow on, How about AJAX and HTML? I am not doing anything complicated could that work. Bascially all the code would be in a HTML5 website and javascript

Comment: I don't know. Are you just reading or also writing to a file on a fileserver? That wouldn't work with AJAX. Probably a reasonable solution would be a Java Application that you deploy on all clients (maybe through [Webstart](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javawebstart/index.html)) which provides access to that file. You could implement a simple locking mechanism to avoid concurrency issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you can only have a folder with files in it then no, you can't use Stripes.  In fact, you can't use any web framework because web frameworks dynamically react to input.  Just having a folder with files in it won't let you dynamically react to input.  You need a server running that can interpret requests.

Comment: I could have the webpage front end as an html file on the network drive and then launch the applet which is in the same folder. Could that work?

Comment: I haven't developed an applet in a while.  I can't say for sure this will satisfy your needs.  You need to tell us a little about your requirements.  Do you need to save/collect data?